# How to get element by tags using JSoup? - java

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing, jsoup

**How to get element by tags using JSoup (http://jsoup.org/)?**

I have the following input and require the following output but i am not getting the text inside the `<source>...<\source>` tags:

**[in:]**

```
<html>
  <something>
    <source>foo bar bar</source>
  <something>
  <source>foo foo bar</source>
</html>
```

**[desired out:]**

```
foo bar bar
foo foo bar
```

I have tried this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class HelloJsoup {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String br = "<html><source>foo bar bar</source></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(br);
        //System.out.println(doc);
        for (Element sentence : doc.getElementsByTag("source"))
            System.out.print(sentence);

    }
}
```

but it outputs:

```
<source></source>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `xmlParser()`, which you can pass in to the `parse()` method:

```
String br = "<html><source>foo bar bar</source></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(br, "", Parser.xmlParser());

for (Element sentence : doc.getElementsByTag("source"))
    System.out.println(sentence.text());

}
```

More on this in the docs: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser()

Comment: Thanks it works but why does adding the xmlParser work?

Comment: The `<source>` tag is new in HTML5, and it appears Jsoup cannot handle it through regular HTML parsing (it must try to validate it against known HTML tags and fail). By using the xmlParser, you can parse any tags (as XML can have arbitrary tag names). Jsoup doesn't try to validate XML documents as being HTML, and simply creates a tree based on whichever sets of tags are in the document.